# neo4j/apoc: How to import a local HTML-file using apoc?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I want to import some information from a local html-file to neo4j.

I have tried to use apoc:

`CALL apoc.load.html("file:///Local.html",{metadata:"meta", h2:"title"})`

The file "Local.html" is inside the import-folder.

This does not work. I get an error:

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke
>   procedure `apoc.load.html`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Can't read the HTML from: file:///Local.html

Is there any way to solve this problem? (Maybe a workaround...)

Comment: (I use neo4j v 3.5.6, apoc v 3.5.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative Path doesn't work in `apoc.load.html`.

You need to provide the full path like:

```
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///<NEO4J_HOME>/import/Local.html",{metadata:"meta", h2:"title"})
```